# Error while creating a new maven project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

Please don't flag this post, as I have tried many solutions but none of them worked.
I tried building a new maven project in my eclipse IDE but got an error like this:-

> Could not resolve archetype
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of
>   the configured repositories. Could not resolve artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1

I tried adding remote catalog in Preference/Maven/Archetypes. But it didn't work.

I have tried to delete the .m2 folder multiple times but that hasn't worked.

Also I tried creating a archtype through command prompt by using this command:

```
C:\Users\Y942>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=fr.myGroupId -DartifactId=MyAppli
cation -Dpackagename=fr.myGroupId -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quicksta
rt
```

The maven gives me this error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the
 plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
repositories [local (C:\Users\Y942\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.
apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I also have tried to add the plugins by downloading them through the org.apache site and manually pasting them into my .m2/repository folder. But it also didn't work.

I think part of my problem is eclipse can't seem to download the dependencies or the plugins required for the project.

Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong? or What else I can do to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which eclipse version you are using ?

Comment: Im using Version: Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Comment: There is next Oxygen and Photon versions available. Do use photon.

Comment: I don't think there is an eclipse version issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other thing that could be going wrong is that your machine is behind a firewall or proxy so your box is not able to hit http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. Try accessing this URL directly in a browser or something to test if you are able to make the request.

Comment: Thank you. The error was the same as you stated above. My company's firewall wasn't allowing eclipse to download the dependencies.

Comment: Please use `https` instead of `http`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to your proxy setting. If you are behind a firewall then its blocking to access remote repository.

Please correct your proxy setting in settings.xml config file of maven.

Locations:

MAVEN_HOME\conf

c:\documents and settings\.m2